# GNOME 3.24 background/wallpaper noise

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell

If I set GNOME 3.24 to use a solid color for its background, it still has something which I can only describe as noise. How to get rid of it? It seems to be a kind of filter on top of the solid color.

Other apps with solid color backgrounds don't display that noise.

I'm using the default theme.